# What's the difference between `.class1.class2` and `.class1 .class2` CSS rule?

Tags: css

I have a table with some rows:

```
<table>
    <tr class="even"><td>tr0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>tr1</td></tr>
    <tr class="even"><td>tr2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have a CSS rule (rule1) for even rows:

```
.even{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I have another rule (rule2) for override the bgcolor of any row:

```
.override, .override.even{
    background-color: green;
}
```

The weird thing is in IE9 all `even` rows (with no `override` class) are green!
Developer tools shows this for `even` rows:

[image]

In these two conditions IE do the job correctly:

If I rewrite rule2 like this:

```
.override, .override .even{ ... }
```

If I move rule2 above rule1:

```
.override, .override.even{ ... }
.even { ... }
```

Question is what's the difference between `.override.even` and `.override .even`?

EDIT:

Thanks for replies. Another question which I forgot to ask is why IE shows the `even` rows green?

Comment: .override .even = Select any element which has a class of "even" that is a decendant of any element that has a class of "override"

Comment: .override.even = Select any element that has a class of "override" or/and "even"

Comment: You need to have some conflicting code somewhere. When I test it, the rows remain blue: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/e3w4q/

Comment: @Jawad: That's not quite right, it will only select elements with *both* classes, not "and/or".

Comment: I am sure I  read it somewhere. I could be wrong. Let me fish!

Comment: @Guffa Yes, fiddle's right but IE shows wrong color.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Yup you are right. My bad - Pedram Behroozi: This one helped me a lot - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref

Comment: If your not not looking to support older browsers, you could use nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even) as alternative!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Spacing in between class specifiers means a ascendant -> descendant relationship.

The rule:

```
.test .heading { font-weight: bold; }
```

Would apply to the `<p>` element here:

```
<span class="test"><p class="heading">Something</p></span>
```

The lack of space means that the element must have both classes for the rule to apply.

The rule:

```
.heading.major { color: blue; }
```

Would apply to the `<p>` element here:

```
<p class="heading major">Major heading</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. But why in IE all `even` rows are green instead of blue?

Comment: spacing does not mean parent -> child relationship. It means acendant -> decendant relationship. A parent is necessarly a ancendant but a ancednat is not necessirly a parent. A child is necessirly a decendant but a desendant is nor necessirly a child.

Answer (score 6):

Both answers are right, but they don't explain, why IE shows both rows green.

It's because IE has "standard" and "quirks" mode. To make multiple classes selectors work, you need to use proper DOCTYPE at the beginning of the file.

You are in "quirks" mode now and IE don't support multiple selectors, it sees only latest class. So it sees this and rows are green:

```
.even {
    background-color: blue;
}
.override, .even {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Put

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

(or another DOCTYPE) at the beginning of the file and both rows are going to be blue as expected.

Comment: How do you know he is in quirks mode?

Comment: Because he has these two rows green and multiple class selectors are not working for him. These two rows should be blue as they are in other browsers.

Comment: +1 This is most likely the reason. Running the fiddle that I linked to in the comments in quirks mode renders the lines with green background.

Answer (score 1):

See the [W3C [CSS] Selector (Level 3) "Recommendation"](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/):

`.override .even` is *two* [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors) separated by a space (which is the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#combinators), CSS is whitespace-sensitive):

> At times, authors may want selectors to describe an element that is the descendant of another element in the document tree (e.g., "an EM element that is contained within an H1 element"). Descendant combinators express such a relationship. **A descendant combinator is whitespace that separates two sequences of simple selectors. A selector of the form "A B" represents an element B that is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.**

This selector will match elements that have the class `even` *if and only if* there exists an ancestor -- not necessarily the parent! -- element with the class `override`. (Unlike characters in some movies, an element *is never* it's own ancestor ;-)

`.override.even` is a [simple selector sequence](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#sequence):

> **A sequence of simple selectors is a chain of simple selectors that are not separated by a combinator.** It always begins with a type selector or a universal selector. No other type selector or universal selector is allowed in the sequence.

A simple selector sequence is evaluated as the [*conjunction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) of the individual simple selectors applied to the same element: that is, it will only match elements *with both* the `override` *and* `even` classes applied.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

`.override .even` is interpreted as "some element with an 'override' class, with another element with a `.even` class nested within. It's basically the same as `ul li`, but applying to CSS classes.

`override.even` is interpreted as "some single element with BOTH override AND even classes".

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="class1">
   <div class="class2">
       <p>test1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If this type coded added than use space between to class like **.class1 .class2**

```
<div class="class1 class2">
   <p>test2</p>
</div>
```

If this type coded added than **don't** use space between to class like **.class1.class2**